# Truncate or trim a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, trim, truncate

I have a list like this:

```
[{'IpProtocol': '-1', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '10.113.97.0/26'}, {'CidrIp': '10.111.0.0/22'}, {'CidrIp': '10.140.0.0/16'}, {'CidrIp': '10.141.0.0/16'}, {'CidrIp': '10.145.0.0/16'}, {'CidrIp': '10.112.0.0/26'}, {'CidrIp': '10.112.0.64/26'}], 'Ipv6Ranges': [], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}]
```

Need trim only the IP's after words CidrIP, only the numbers:

10.113.97.0/26
10.111.0.0/22
10.140.0.0/16
...

How it's this possible? I tested with s.strip or map but don't get it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: iterate over the list of dicts and collect their values. Try

Comment: What do you mean by "trim"? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
ips = data.get('IpRanges', []) # get the IpRanges list from main dict
ips = [ip['CidrIp'] for ip in ips] # iterate over Ipranges list and get value of CidrIp.
print(ips)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of list comprehension and string manipulation to extract only the IP addresses from the list of dictionaries. Here's an example code that should work:

```
data = [{'IpProtocol': '-1', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '10.113.97.0/26'}, {'CidrIp': '10.111.0.0/22'}, {'CidrIp': '10.140.0.0/16'}, {'CidrIp': '10.141.0.0/16'}, {'CidrIp': '10.145.0.0/16'}, {'CidrIp': '10.112.0.0/26'}, {'CidrIp': '10.112.0.64/26'}], 'Ipv6Ranges': [], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}]

ip_list = [ip['CidrIp'].split('/')[0] for item in data for ip in item['IpRanges']]
print(ip_list)
```

This returns the following:

```
['10.113.97.0', '10.111.0.0', '10.140.0.0', '10.141.0.0', '10.145.0.0', '10.112.0.0', '10.112.0.64']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```py
AIM = [i["CidrIp"] for i in DATA[0].get("IpRanges")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the data object is store into variable called `data`

```
 data = [{'IpProtocol': '-1', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '10.113.97.0/26'}, {'CidrIp': '10.111.0.0/22'}, {'CidrIp': '10.140.0.0/16'}, {'CidrIp': '10.141.0.0/16'}, {'CidrIp': '10.145.0.0/16'}, {'CidrIp': '10.112.0.0/26'}, {'CidrIp': '10.112.0.64/26'}], 'Ipv6Ranges': [], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}]
```

Now, use list comprehension to extract all IP Address

```
ip_address_list = [ip['CidrIp'] for ip in data[0]['IpRanges']]
```

The output result is

```
['10.113.97.0/26', '10.111.0.0/22', '10.140.0.0/16', '10.141.0.0/16', '10.145.0.0/16', '10.112.0.0/26', '10.112.0.64/26']
```

If you want to get only Address

```
ip_address_list = [ip['CidrIp'].split('/')[0] for ip in data[0]['IpRanges']]
```

The result is

```
['10.113.97.0', '10.111.0.0', '10.140.0.0', '10.141.0.0', '10.145.0.0', '10.112.0.0', '10.112.0.64']
```

If you want to get only Subnet Mask

```
subnet_mask_list = [int(ip['CidrIp'].split('/')[1]) for ip in data[0]['IpRanges']]
```

The result is

```
[26, 22, 16, 16, 16, 26, 26]
```

You can also use `ipaddress` library to resolve IP Address and separate into Address and Subnet Mask

```
import ipaddress

for ip in data[0]['IpRanges']:
     net = ipaddress.ip_network(ip['CidrIp'])
     print('Address :', net.network_address, ' Subnet Mask :', net.netmask)
```

The output result

```
Address : 10.113.97.0  Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.192
Address : 10.111.0.0  Subnet Mask : 255.255.252.0
Address : 10.140.0.0  Subnet Mask : 255.255.0.0
Address : 10.141.0.0  Subnet Mask : 255.255.0.0
Address : 10.145.0.0  Subnet Mask : 255.255.0.0
Address : 10.112.0.0  Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.192
Address : 10.112.0.64  Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.192
```